# Moving TFS to a server in a different domain

Tags: team-foundation-server

There are other variations of this question on SO, but none that cover our exact situation.

Current situation:

- We have TFS 2008 on a stand alone server.
- We have created local user accounts to login to TFS.
- We use TFS for source control, task assignment and bug tracking.
- We use a modified version of a scrum template.

We now want to move TFS to a server in a domain.

Questions are:

- From what I have read the TFS Migration Tool does not work between domains. Is this correct?
- Can we backup TFS from the existing server at restore it to the other?
- What will happen to all the items that are connected to users?
- What do the developers need to do on their machines to start getting code from the new server? (We have previously had problems that we cannot get latest to a location because it is being used by a different workspace)

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful ... [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we ended up just moving the scrum template and the source code without the history.